# J2ME polish problems when running on phones

Tags: java-me, arabic, j2mepolish

I built an application with j2me polish,it works well on emulator but after installing on phones, I have some basic problems:

1. At first why the size of application is big(in my case 1.5 mb),is there any way to decrease polish apps size(my resources are just 300 kb).

Also installing process takes long in some mobile phones in comparing with similar apps in this level.

1. For installing it on the phone, I copy the jar file from dist folder; Is my way correct?
2. Important!:arabic words in some SonyEricsson phones are seprated and reversed, I searched the web, but I just found some topics about LWUIT and I coulden't solve it on polish!

Comment: 1) Are you already using an obfuscator?

Comment: I think yes,j2me polish has auto obfuscator.

Comment: @RezaHasht, I dont think polish has auto obfuscator

Comment: yes it has in build.xml file:    <obfuscator name="ProGuard" unless="test or               polish.blackberry" >
                    <parameter name="optimize" value="true" />
     
                </obfuscator>

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for my first and second question by helping  Telmo Pimentel Mota and Lucifer.
the answer is:

```
 <obfuscator name="ProGuard" unless="test or polish.blackberry" >
                <parameter name="optimize" value="true" />
                <parameter name="optimizationpasses" value="3"/>                    
            </obfuscator>
```

but third question is still remained.

Comment: So, initially optimize was false and then you change it to true?

Comment: yes I think but the second line is more important(optimizationpasses).